# initialize a list to a provider's list in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class AppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Note> _notes = [];

  List<Note> get getNotes {
    return _notes;
  }
}
```

and here is homescreen code

i have a list named searchedNotes here, want to initilize it with provider's list, when app starts

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  TextEditingController txtname=TextEditingController();
  List<Note> searchedNotes=[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // how to assign searchedNotes to provider's notes;;
  }
```

Comment: How do you add the values in the list?

Comment: I know that but i have just shared minimum code..my main query is to fetch provider's data to homescreen in init

Answer (score 1):

There must be data in the list thereafter. simply do this

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
   searchedNotes = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen:false).getNotes; //this will return empty because it is empty not until you add a method to add.
  }
```

Comment: here morthing that i want to know...whats the difference if i add toList searchedNotes = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen:false).getNotes.toList

Comment: you won't get context for it. you probably get context not found error in initState()
so assign the value in didchangedependencies or build method.

Comment: It will have context issues. You already declared it as a list.

Comment: Do you want to create/add a values in the empty list?